# AH00035: access to / denied 403 Forbidden Django mod-wsgi

Tags: apache-2.4, mod-wsgi

I am trying to configure apache with Django using mod-wsgi. But I am getting the following error

```
AH00035: access to / denied (filesystem path '/home/ec2-user/ezvoice') because search permissions are missing on a component of the path
```

URL is showing `403 forbidden`
Here is the conf file

```
LoadModule wsgi_module "/home/ec2-user/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/mod_wsgi/server/mod_wsgi-py37.cpython-37m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so"
<VirtualHost *:80>
        DocumentRoot /home/ec2-user/

        Alias /static /home/ec2-user/ezvoice/sub_app/static
        <Directory /home/ec2-user/ezvoice/sub_app/static>
                Options FollowSymLinks
                Order allow,deny
                Require all granted
        </Directory>


        WSGIDaemonProcess ezvoice python-path=/home/ec2-user/ezvoice:/home/ec2-user/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages
        WSGIProcessGroup ezvoice
        WSGIScriptAlias / /home/ec2-user/ezvoice/main_app/wsgi.py
    ErrorLog /home/ec2-user/ezvoice/log-error.log
    CustomLog /home/ec2-user/ezvoice/custom-error.log combined
        <Directory /home/ec2-user/ezvoice/main_app>
                <Files wsgi.py>
                        Require all granted
                </Files>
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

The directory structure is as follow

```
home
-ec2-user
--ezvoice
---main_app
----asgi.py
----settings.py
---sub_app
----views.py
--venv
---bin
---include
---lib
```

I have tried to set permission as follow

```
sudo chown ec2-user ezvoice
sudo chown -R ec2-user /usr/local/lib/python3.7
sudo chown ec2-user /usr/local/bin
sudo chown ec2-user /usr/local/lib
```

Answer (score 1):

"Search permissions are missing" means that the Apache user (probably apache, or www-data) doesn't have permission to traverse the directory tree all the way down to /home/ec2-user/ezvoice. You can debug this with `namei -l`, which will show you a long listing of all of the directory paths down to a file or directory, starting from /. For example:

```
$ namei -l /home/testuser
f: /home/testuser
dr-xr-xr-x root     root  /
drwxr-xr-x root     root  home
drwx------ testuser users testuser
```

When you do this for /home/ec2-user/ezvoice, you'll probably see that one of the directories along the path - maybe /, judging from the error message - is missing the `x` permission for group or other, which allows users to traverse the directory tree through that directory.

A simple solution is to give all users the traverse permission on all of those directories:

```
chmod go+x / /home /home/ec2-user /home/ec2-user/ezvoice
```

Then compare the output of `namei -l` again to see what changed. If you don't want to grant such broad permissions, you could do it more carefully for just the Apache user, with a file ACL:

```
setfacl -m u:apache:x / /home /home/ec2-user /home/ec2-user/ezvoice
```

Note, changing the ownership of Python isn't a good idea. You should be able to fix the permissions of the files that Python and Apache read, rather than the programs themselves.